# SQL Correct Syntax for Selecting between 3 category in the field

Tags: c#, sql, wpf, ms-access

I just want to know how to create SQL syntax in MS access.

What I want to do is I am going to select the from the table which name is `Employee`, where the fieldname (position) is equal to `Manager`, `Supervisor`, `Acting Supervisor`, and the fieldname (status) is equal to `active`.

My code found below does not work:

```
SQL = "SELECT * FROM `Employee` WHERE `position`= '" + "Manager" + "' OR `position`= '" + "Supervisor" + "' OR `position`= '" + "Acting Supervisor WHERE `status`= '" +"ACTIVE"'";
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't really need all that string concatenation, you're missing a quote after `Acting Supervsior`, and you can't have the `WHERE` keyword twice - use `AND` instead.

```
SQL = "SELECT * FROM `Employee` WHERE (`position` = 'Manager' OR `position` = 'Supervisor' OR `position` = 'Acting Supervisor') AND `status` = 'ACTIVE'";
```

**Update**

You could also simplify the logic a bit by using the `IN` keyword:

```
SQL = "SELECT * FROM `Employee` WHERE `position` IN ('Manager', 'Supervisor', 'Acting Supervisor') AND `status` = 'ACTIVE'";
```